# вывести слова в порядке убывания их длин

Tags: python

Вывести слова в порядке убывания их длин, от самого длинного - к самому короткому.

Строку инициализировать в коде программы:

> So she was considering in her own mind, as well as she could, for the
>   hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid,  whether  the  pleasure 
>   of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and 
>   picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran
>   close by her.

Comment: Что Вы сделали? Что Вы хотите? Чем Вам помочь?

Comment: что значит слово? (например, "daisy-chain" это одно слово или два?) Как длину считать? (кол-во байт в utf-8 кодировке? кол-во Unicode codepoints in NFC? Кол-во видимых пользователю букв?)

Answer (score 2):

```
src = 'So she was considering in her own mind, as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid, whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.'
print '\n'.join(sorted(set([x.strip('.,').lower() for x in src.split(' ')]), key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True))
```

Comment: ответ работает только для ascii текста, в котором слова разделены пробелами и который содержит только точку и запятую как знаки препинания. В общем случае ответ неверен: существуют другие пробельные символы кроме `'\x20'`, существуют другие символы, которые не являются частью слова, кроме `'.,'`. `bytes.lower()` может вернуть неверные результаты в не-ascii случае. Буквы могут быть представлены, используя разное кол-во байт в зависимости от кодировки. Используйте Unicode, `casefold()`, явно определите в вашем ответе, что вы считаете "словом". Используйте `key=len`, вместо `key=lambda x: len(x)`